# Grouping on search result - RavenDB

Tags: c#, full-text-search, ravendb, faceted-search

I have an index which displays text search results. Results are always displayed only for a single month.

I need to show how many results does each month has. Example is at the bottom.

I understand that Faceted search should do the job, but creating/generating ranges manualy is not possible and it would result in huge amount of ranges.
I tried everything from official documentation, even ResultTransformers which is not the right tool. So I hope I must have overlooked something.

```
Map = transactions => from transaction in transactions
select new
    {
        Description = new object[] { transaction.Description, transaction.Items.Select(i => i.Name), transaction.Documents.Select(i => i.Name) },
        Account_UserName = transaction.Account.UserName,
        Time = transaction.Time
    };
```

Result I expect is something like this:

```
 [{
    Year: 2013,
    Month: 12,
    Count: 3
 },
 {
    Year: 2013,
    Month: 11,
    Count: 10
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that [Dynamic aggregation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/dynamic-aggregation) will do the job. I've added field month, because anonymous object didn't work.

```
Map = transactions => from transaction in transactions
select new
    {
        Value = transaction.Value,
        Description = new object[] { transaction.Description, transaction.Items.Select(i => i.Name) },
        Account_UserName = transaction.Account.UserName,
        Time = transaction.Time,
        Month = new DateTime(transaction.Time.Year, transaction.Time.Month, 1) // new field
    };
```

And then extended query by `.AggregateBy(x => x.Month).CountOn(x => x.Month);`

```
var result = _session.Query<Transaction, Transaction_Search>()
    .AggregateBy(x => x.Month)
    .CountOn(x => x.Month);
```

This produces, after some transformation, desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You want to stamp each index record with a Month value and go from there:

```
Map = transactions => from transaction in transactions
select new
    {
        Description = new object[] { transaction.Description, transaction.Items.Select(i => i.Name), transaction.Documents.Select(i => i.Name) },
        Account_UserName = transaction.Account.UserName,
        Month = transaction.Time.Month + "/" + transaction.Time.Year, // To be able to group on Months
        Time = transaction.Time
    };
```

From there you can either use faceting on the Month field, or use a Reduce function to index Months with the totals to make this calculation searchable

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how adding month field would help me. I have tried map/reduce index with fields:
**Description** - which I query on,
**UserName**,
**Year**,
**Month**,
**Count**. But setting Description to null to make results group properly stopped index from working.
I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Because then you can use the Month field as the reduce key. You can still do this with `group by new { time.Month, time.Year }` but my personal preference would be to have them in one field for readability.

Comment: Reading your comment again - if you want to query on Description you can't use Map/Reduce really, only facets.